# PHP Regex to match and return optional part of pattern

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to move my router to use regex but struggling to get the following right.

I work with a simple module (controller)/action/parameters URI but parameters is obviously optional and can be a single or multiple parameters, depending on the method.

Sample Pattern: /pages/view
Sample URI: /pages/view/about_us/mobile

Using preg_match, I would like to match the URI to the pattern even if it only is a partial match but would like to capture and use the about_us/mobile (or whatever it may be).

I'm trying to make my dispatcher as generic as possible and would like to avoid the scenario that I would have to add a route for each parameter I would pass into a given action/method. If I could capture the about_us/mobile I could use explode to make it an array an pass it into the given controllers method.

I assume I would need to change my pattern to do so, but I have no idea how to do this? Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use a regex.  Use `split` to break apart the path on slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:** `#^/([^/]+)/?([^/]+)?/?(.*)?$#`

The first match group will be your controller, the second match group will be an optional action, and the third match group will be optional parameters (everything to the end of the string).

**Explanation:**

```
#^            -- delimiter and beginning of string
  /([^/]+)    -- / followed by a match of everything until the next /
  /?([^/]+)?  -- optional / optionally followed by a match of everything until the next /
  /?(.*)?     -- optional / optionally followed by anything else
$#            -- end of string and delimiter
```

**Note:** I used `#` as delimiters so that you didn't need to escape every `/`.